# use index in ItemSeperatorComponent

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use the current index in `ItemSeparatorComponent` as shown below, however `index` is always empty and never returns a value, but `item` is successfully populated. I'd really appreciate it if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
<FlatList
          numColumns={1}
          data={messages}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => <OFChatBubble message={item} />}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={(item, index) => (
            <DateSeparator item={item} index={index} />
          )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To debug correctly you can try to add a `debugger` like this

```js
ItemSeparatorComponent={(item, index) => {
  debugger

  return (
    <DateSeparator item={item} index={index} />
  )
}}
```

Open Chrome with the source tab opened to figure out the format of `data={messages}`

Comment: `messages` is an array of objects - FlatList sees each object as an `item` at the `index` of this array - `renderItem` knows the index, it appears `ItemListSeparator` does not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just forgot the `{ }`around the params in the arrow function you passed to ItemSeparatorComponent

The code should be:

```
ItemSeparatorComponent={({item, index}) => (
        <DateSeparator item={item} index={index} />
)}
```

Edit:

I was wrong ItemSeparatorComponent does not get the same props as renderItem. It gets `highlighted:boolean, leadingItem:<an object from the data you pass in>` but you still need to use `{ }` in order to get them

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I tried wrapping the params but this results in the properties both returning `undefined`

Comment: I just checked it on my machine and I was wrong apparently you get an object like this:`"highlighted": false,   
  "leadingItem": Object { 
  },`